Monster themed universe book series with a woman on the cover in blue with three mini-stories inside all connected to each other
It was a bit of a larger book, it had three separate stories with a connecting universe, this would have been volume 2 of that series. The cover had a woman on the front in black and white with blue details
The first novella is so vivid but unclear, but it’s a teenage girl who I think gets into an accident and meets a “guardian angel” of some sort, and he’s nice but then he sort of screws around with her life and such, and I don't know if he has a fake name or not (I can barely remember) but the girl finds out about the monsters in town, that she's from a lineage of witches, and also finds out her guardian angel is a dead boy named Gabriel who I think wanted revenge?

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Was it a hardcover or paperback?

@DavidW It was a paperback. A thick paperback. I don't exactly remember when I read it, but I believe the copyright of the book was in between 2000-2013, somewhere in there. I've been trying to find it for so long.
